# write a block that will not apear in the published page

Tags: php

I want to write a block for my own use only, but not to be visible when the page is read in a browser.

Comment: What kind of block do you want to write? Are you searching a possibility do document your code?

Comment: What? i dont understand this Q

Answer (score 2):

Maybe commenting it?

HTML:

```
<!-- comment... -->
```

PHP:

```
/* comment 1 */
// comment 2
#  comment 3
```

Comment: dont forget `#` -- hash comments

Comment: @Neal: Thank! Forgot that altogether!

Comment: The HTML comments will not prevent the browser from revealing their contents if the user views the source of the page.

Comment: @Asaph: Yes, but if you don't have a server-side language, that's as close as your going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*
This is a server side comment that will not be visible on the client side.
*/
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and does exactly what I wanted

Comment: @awy: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this:

```
<?php
     // code for them

     if (isset($_GET['debug'])) {
         // code for me
     }
?>
```

When I need access to the debug code, i just browse to http://mysite.com/page.php?debug

*Obviously, this isn't secure. Anybody can simply add `?debug` to the URL and see your debug info. This would be something to use during initial development of a one-off script hosted locally, and is not suitable for use on a public-facing site.*

Comment: But then everyone else in the world can see your debug info by doing the same thing.

Comment: @Asaph: Only if they know how. OP didn't ask for a **secure** method.

Comment: @jnpcl: That's called [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is widely considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: @Asaph: Considering the vagueness of the OP's question, it's probably a bit over his head to post an answer complete with authentication/password-hashing/session-verification etc.

Comment: @jnpcl: authentication/password-hashing/session-verification would be total overkill where a simple server side comment would suffice. Capturing debug information and other instrumentation (which is a completely different question) should be done through logging controlled on the server side, not in the client side manner you've suggested.

Comment: @Asaph: OP was not clear in what they wanted.. I assumed by `a block` they meant a block they could see on the page as an admin.

Comment: @jnpcl: I will grant you that the question was worded poorly and certainly subject to interpretation.

Comment: @Asaph: Thanks for the concern, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comments like // /* */ and #
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

It's the only way that visitors won't see your text blocks.